# InvalidOperationException when loading SoundEffect in XNA

Tags: xna, content-management-system, xna-4.0, audio

I am loading a number of sound effects for a game. On a number of computers the following call:

```
SoundEffect effect = ContentPersistentAudio.Load<SoundEffect>(location);
```

works without problems. On one specific computer, however, it crashes throwing an `InvalidOperationException` exception. What could go wrong? The computer on which it crashes has a normal sound-on-board with properly installed drivers (is this even necessary). The content manager seems properly initialized and the location is also correct (works fine elsewhere).

A example audio file is available at: http://www.hybridbeasts.com/test.wav

Interestingy, a try/catch fails and still produces an application crash.

```
        try
        {
            effect = Content.Load<SoundEffect>(location);
        }
        catch
        {
            Warning.Happened("Problem with audio playback detected. Sound automatically disabled");
            DebugEngine.disableSound = true;
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Can you open the sound file on that computer with another program, for example Windows Media Player?

Comment: Interestingly, I can't. There is an error message stating that the sound cannot be played (not the literal text which is in german ;-)). VLC player is able to play it but cannot display proper media information. The sound itself is a WAV file.

Comment: When you copy this file to a computer which is presumably working, is it playable there, in Windows Media Player and XNA?

Comment: It plays without a problem (with Windows Media Player) on a computer where it is working in XNA. Is there any way to test this properly (and preventing the application from simply cashing)? It should be possible to verify somehow if a given sound is playable given in certain driver/codec installation and hardware setup environment, shouldn't it?

Comment: What with a simple try-catch?

Comment: Yes, I could disable the sound engine in a catch block if the error occurs. Thanks for the idea! However, can anyone tell what is wrong with the audio file? I uploaded it at http://www.hybridbeasts.com/test.wav

Comment: do you maybe receive _"Song playback failed. Please verify that the song is not DRM protected. DRM protected songs are not supported for creator games."_ error ?

Comment: No, the wav is not DRM protected.

Comment: Does anyone understand why the above try/catch construction does not work?